# How put php variable

Tags: php, variables

I have this function:

```
function api()
{
    $date = time()- 86400;
    
    $method = "getOrders";
    
            $methodParams = '{
                "date_confirmed_from": $date,
                "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
            }';
            $apiParams = [
                "method" => $method,
                "parameters" => $methodParams
            ];
            
            $curl = curl_init("https://api.domain.com");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["X-BLToken:xxx"]);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiParams));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
        
            return $response;
}
```

I want to put on line 8 variable date and I have tried `{$date}` `$date` `'.$date.'`  `".$date."`  every time I get error from api

If I put value manually like 1589972726  it working, but I need to get value from $date variable!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: You have to use doublequotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` if you want variables to be injected in the string.

Comment: $methodParams = '{
                "date_confirmed_from": ' . $date. ',
                "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
            }';

Comment: Don't manually create your json like that. Just create a PHP array with the correct structure and use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn it into json.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is less confusing, if you use an array and convert it to the needed format later:

```
$methodParams = [
   "date_confirmed_from" => $date,
   "get_unconfirmed_orders" => false
];
$apiParams = [
   "method" => $method,
   "parameters" => json_encode($methodParams)
];
```

Have a look at the documentation of `json_encode`for details:

https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php

Anyways, using the same quotes that started the string to close it, should work too:

```
$methodParams = '{
    "date_confirmed_from": ' . $date . ',
    "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
}';
```

Comment: The `json_encode()`-path is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have single quote on that string, you need to inject with single quote: **`'.$date.'`**,

if you would have double quote you use **`{$date}`** or **`\"$date\"`**

```
$methodParams = '{
                "date_confirmed_from": '.$date.',
                "get_unconfirmed_orders": false
            }';
```